# GWT 2.4 DataGrid row span

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to have a DataGrid with a column that contains mixture of different row spans of 2, 4, etc? I've come across DataGrid's setTableBuilder() method in CustomDataGrid sample code http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid

However in GWT 2.4, setTableBuilder() method doesn't exist. For older GWT, is it possible to achieve row span for DataGrid widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method was added in commit 642e965, which was released in GWT 2.5 and is present in later versions as well. It is [not a small commit](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/642e965131e2cfa0905212fddf3052ad0a1e3061%5E!/), as it had to replace entirely how the DataGrid and CellTable were rendering their content with an external system.

> This API change required a significant refactor of CellTable because CellTable assumed a grid structure with one row per row value, one cell per column, and a structure consisting of a div inside of a td for every Cell.

You might be able to build a custom GWT version off of 2.4 with only this additional patch, or perhaps copy the classes after they were changed and use them with GWT 2.4. This seems possible since no changes were made to the compiler, but is not a small change.

Additionally, GWT 2.4.0 is over five years old - there have certainly been many other fixes introduced in the meantime.